# Lost .pem file. Need help connecting to EC2 remote server

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

My secretary created a new instance in Amazon using their EC2 server but lost the .pem file. Doing research online I was able to go to the instance system settings/get system log and retrieve some type of password there. The instance system log shows something like this:

```
2019/04/15 12:15:19Z: Username: Username
2019/04/15 12:15:19Z: Password: <Password>
```

It is a very long code of random characters.

Is there any way I can use this to log in via remote desktop or is there a way to decrypt it? I tried several decryption methods online and they said this was not a valid "hash"...whatever this means. I am not a technical person so I need hopefully a response in layman terms.

Comment: Try asking Amazon support, but I think you're out of luck. If this is a new instance, why not just delete and make a new one? Also, you shouldn't be calling someone dumb on this site.

Comment: There is already stuff on the server. Basically, I need to know if the password that I found in the system log can be used, unencrypted, etc. I cannot ask Amazon because they charge for support and I don't have support with them.

Comment: No, that hashed password cannot be used. Even if you knew the password, password login is turned off by default. Try file recovery software on the computer which had the pem file.

Comment: @Denison You can sign up for the $49/month level of support, and cancel after your support case. Should only wind up costing a couple bucks. If you can afford a secretary with devops skills, you can probably afford that.

Comment: Is there anything important on the instance? If not, terminate it and launch another one.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are connecting to a **Windows** instance. When a new Amazon EC2 Windows instance is launched, a program on the AMI (disk image) **automatically generates a random `Administrator` password**. This is done so that *you* can access the instance, but nobody else can.

To keep the password secret, the program **encrypts the password with the keypair** nominated when the instance was launched. The encrypted password is passed back to AWS via the console. That is the string of 'random characters' you saw.

To decrypt the password, you can use the **Get Windows Password** feature, which requires you to supply the nominated keypair. It will then decrypt the password, which can be used to login to the instance as `Administrator`.

Since you no longer have the keypair, you cannot decrypt the password and therefore cannot login to the server. This is good! This **proves that security works**, because you would not want other people to be able to login to the server.

So, can do you regain access?

**Refer to the steps on:** [I need to reset the administrator password on a Windows Server instance in Amazon EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-admin-password/)

Basically, there are two methods:

- If Systems Manager is enabled for the instance, you can run a "rescue" script
- Otherwise, there is a series of scripts that assist with the process of:

  - Detaching the disk
  - Attaching it to another instance
  - Resetting a configuration on the disk
  - Reattaching the disk to the original instance

The second process is a bit like plugging a USB disk into another computer to change a file (except that EC2 disks are managed differently).